# HTML form validaton rules from CakePHP model validation

Tags: html, validation, cakephp

Is there any way to FormHelper generate HTML validation attributes in input tag for rules defined in the model?

e.g. in model

```php
var $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank',
        'required' => true
    )
);
```

in view

```php
echo $this->Form->input('title');
```

HTML in browser

```
<input type="text" title="This field cannot be left blank" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the validation criteria from your controller using `$this->Model->validate`:

```
//controller
$this->set('validation', $this->Model->validate);
```

And then you could use it in the view if you wish but... I don't think CakePHP implements anything similar to what you are looking for, so you could try to create a helper for this purpose extending the Form helper.

Comment: I am thinking about to extend FormHelper and implement this functionality. Tnx on advice!